# How to create a new <li> in html with <span> inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, html-lists

Hello I've a problem with HTML and JavaScript:

I have an `<ul>` list without any `<li>`...
There is a button which has to create a new `<li>` with a `<span>` inside...
I have no idea how to do it...
This is the code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function somma(){
    var stringaFinestra=tipoFinestra + " " + tipoColore + " \u20ac" + costo;
    var ul = document.getElementById("preventiviArea");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("class", "w3-display-container");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stringaFinestra));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="w3-button w3-orange w3-round-xxlarge" type="button" value="AGGIUNGI" onclick="somma()" style="width:200px; height:50px;">

<ul id="preventiviArea" class="w3-ul w3-card-4 w3-white">
</ul>
```

I use w3 for the graphics and i want to have this final result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <ul id="preventiviArea" class="w3-ul w3-card-4 w3-white">
      <li class="w3-display-container">demo<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-transparent w3-display-right">&times;</span></li>
     </ul>
```

Thanks to all for the help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I think your code should work. What's the problem with it?

Comment: You're missing the span. You need to create that in the same way, and use `li.appendChild(span)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new span and append it into your `li`

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = '&times;';
span.setAttribute("class", "w3-button w3-transparent w3-display-right");
span.onclick = function() { this.parentElement.style.display='none' };
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stringaFinestra));
li.appendChild(span);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `<li>` is the child of `<ul>` tag similarly `<span>` is supposed to be the child of `<li>` tag So you should do the same thing you did before

```
var ul = document.getElementById("preventiviArea");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.setAttribute("class", "w3-display-container");
li.setAttribute("id", "something");
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stringaFinestra));
ul.appendChild(li);
var li = document.getElementById("something");
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.setAttribute("class", "w3-button w3-transparent w3-display-right");
span.setAttribute("onclick", "this.parentElement.style.display='none'");
span.textContent="times"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```js
function somma(){
  var ul = document.getElementById("preventiviArea");
  var newSpan = document.createElement("span"); 
  newSpan.classList.add("w3-display-container")
  var newLi = document.createElement("span"); 
  newSpan.innerHTML= "&times;"
  newSpan.onclick = function() { this.parentElement.style.display='none' };
  newLi.appendChild(newSpan);
  ul.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var span= document.createElement('span');

span.value='Item';

var li = document.createElement('li');

document.getElementById('preventiviArea').appendChild(span).appendChild(span);